# Compact Convention

Tags: javascript, coding-style, convention

In the case that each method and variable will only be used **once**, which is the more correct convention?

Creating as many variables as necessary:

```
var x = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
var email = GmailApp.getInboxThreads (0, x);
```

Composing the code in one line:

```
var email = GmailApp.getInboxThreads (0, GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter, within reason.  But this is largely a matter of style in the simple cases.

Meaning that if you have a function call that takes 10 arguments, and each of those arguments comes from a large function call itself, dont do this. Think of who gets your code base afterward.

"Is this line of code readable using less local variables? Or do I need to break it up to better illustrate what the line is doing?" is the question you should ask yourself.  And in this case, the latter is totally readable.

---

In fact, I would argue the first example is less readable due to a useless local variable name `x`.  If instead that were named better, it might be a more viable option.

```
var unreadCount = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
var email = GmailApp.getInboxThreads (0, unreadCount);
```

This is better, but still pretty unnecessary in this very simple case.

Comment: Another important point is the space the extra characters occupy in your javascript files. Since these files must be downloaded by the client, the extra characters might have some weight on the final download size. Of course you can wlways obfuscate/minify/compress your file or this might not be an issue at all, for your particular infra-structure... Still, you should be aware of it.

Comment: Technically that is true, but the difference is pretty minimal, especially when gzipped.  And there is no excuse for serving ungzipped js these days.  And if you are an environment where those few bytes matter, then you better be using a compressor as well, which would probably refactor this for on compile anyway.  So there is really not much an excuse for making it harder to maintain to save bandwidth.  Let automated tools do that for you, and write the highest quality code you can.

Comment: Bandwidth is not an issue for me but that's good to know for future reference. Thanks for your answer, this reminds me of theory that "your code may only be written once, but it may be read 1000 times".

Comment: I absolutely agree with you but, as I said, the poster should be aware that other issues might come into play (just as a sidenote, the difference might not be so minimal; almost 20% of your re-written example are extra chars ;-)).

Comment: @Isoliveira fair enough.  I just irks me when people make excuses for hard to understand code.  But I get what you're saying and it's totally valid.

Answer (score 1):

It's a trade off.

The first example is easier to read and debug. It has 2 lines where errors can occur. For debugging this is good because there is only one function being called per line.

The second example is called a "one liner" and can be tricky to debug because there are multiple things that could cause errors on that line, but uses less memory. Probably an insignificant amount though.

In this example,

```
1. var unread = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
2. var email = GmailApp.getInboxThreads (0, unread);
```

Say you get an error on line 2. you know that getInboxThreads is throwing the error.

```
1. var email = GmailApp.getInboxThreads (0, GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount());
```

Now say you get an error on line 1. You'll have to check both methods.

Comment: So it really comes down to what I think looks easier to debug.